# How to draw lines with different colors in Openlayers 2?

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to display multiple polylines with different colors in openlayers. Can any one guide me regarding this.

I have done this in google maps. but i don't know how to do it in openlayers. I am newbie to Openlayers.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every feature has a [style property](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.style) which is null by default because it inherits the parent vector layer's style. But you can set the style for each feature:

## DEMO

[image]

[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/XzKvP/1/)

**Code Example:**

```js
var myFirstLineStyle = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(myFirstLineStyle, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
myFirstLineStyle.strokeColor = "#ffffff";
myFirstLineStyle.strokeWidth = 8;
firstFeature.style = myFirstLineStyle;

var mySecondLineStyle = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(mySecondLineStyle, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
mySecondLineStyle.strokeColor = "#000000";
mySecondLineStyle.strokeWidth = 4;
secondFeature.style = mySecondLineStyle;
```

If you change the styles of the features after they've been added to the layer you must call `layer.redraw()`.

[More on Styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYe5N.png)

Comment: working like a charm...

Comment: i have updated my question with image can u look into it and guide me according to that.

Comment: I don't see a question. Regardless, i would recommend you post a separate question and reference this one if you like. Changing questions after they have been answered and dragging them on is not good etiquette. I'll be happy to help, just post a new question and revert this one back to how it was.

Answer (score 1):

Wow,

Instead of all this, u can configure your style with attribute replacement](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html#attribute-replacement-syntax).

Then when a new feature is draw you have to intercept the `featureAdded` event and set the field to use in the replacement.