# How to draw Geodesic lines in Openlayers 2?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2

I want to display multiple lines between two coordinates. I will pass number of lines and color of the line, it has to display like below image.

please see the below image.[this is my previous post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21612/how-to-display-multiple-polylines-with-different-colors-in-openlayers)
[image]

Comment: Did you want Geodesic lines?

Comment: You mean you will pass two coordinates and color of the line? Intead of "i will pass no of lines and color of the line"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This demo takes in two coordinates and a color and will create a [Geodesic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) line between them.

**[DEMO LINK](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/ol/geodesic_line.html)**

[image]

You can add lines by entering information into the form, **OR programmatically** like so:

```js
//Taj Mahal to Venice (San Marco)
AddLineProgrammatically(new OpenLayers.LonLat(78.0447, 27.17461), new OpenLayers.LonLat(12.34014, 45.43338), "#006633");
//Roman Coliseum to Mecca
AddLineProgrammatically(new OpenLayers.LonLat(12.49249, 41.89014), new OpenLayers.LonLat(39.8261238221, 21.4225222672), "#feadc8");
// Mecca to Statue of Liberty
AddLineProgrammatically(new OpenLayers.LonLat(39.8261238221, 21.4225222672), new OpenLayers.LonLat(-74.04457, 40.68927), "#3366cc");
```

This demo is based off of [Mr. Wippermann great circle example](http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL26/examples/gc_example.html).

## Update per comment:

Simply comment out this line: `vectorLayer.addFeatures([pointFeature, pointFeature2]);` in the AddLine and AddLineProgrammatically functions if you don't want the markers.

[image]

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: A small modification, now i dont want to display markers, will add markers through the markers layer. So i need only lines from this vector layer. Can u help me?

Comment: simply comment out this line: `vectorLayer.addFeatures([pointFeature, pointFeature2]);` in the `AddLine` and `AddLineProgrammatically` functions.

Comment: hi one more small modification, i want remove all lines on an event. how to do that...

Comment: That looks like a new question to me - perhaps you should post it as one. I'll be glad to answer it then.

Comment: thanks i have achieved this by adding vectorLayer.removeFeatures(); on click function

Comment: Hi @CaptDragon. Could you please repost your example. The demo link appears to be dead. The "Mr. Wippermann great circle example" seems rather complicated. Thanks a lot.